# Бесконечность vs бескрайность (или что там ещё?)

Tags: значение-слов, филозабавы

Все мы были маленькими. И задавали прекрасные вопросы. Теперь наши дети, в основном в возрасте от 6 до 9, задают те же вопросы, что и мы в их годы (хотя почему-то я лично задавала их несколько раньше шести лет). Спрашивают же о "размерах" Вселенной (Космоса), употребляя понятие **бесконечность**. И вот давеча я задумалась, присмотревшись к значениям этого слова: а имеет ли оно, слово это, право на второе значение (**бескрайность**)? Ведь бесконечность как бы подразумевает существование начала, лишь оговаривая, что у чего-либо нет конца и края. Зачем тогда смешивать это понятие с бескрайностью? И подпункт вопроса: насколько приставка бес- (без-) древняя и как она могла входить в наш язык.

- Апдейт. И, кстати, вечность куда шире по смыслу, а уж какие
  диковинные синонимы у нее! Например, вневременность какая-нибудь.
  Вроде бы вечность именно о бескрайности времени шепчет, а он как -
  она вне его! Ну, это уже пошла иная песня...(Smile)

Answer (score 1):

Насчет приставочек скромно промолчу, а вот на "основной" вопрос вы фактически в своем же "апдейте" и ответили. Что понятие "бесконечность" по умолчанию шире и что оно потому и чаще употребительно в отношении Вселенной - ведь речь идет не только о "географических" пределах. Вот, кстати, а можно ее еще и беспредельной называть)

Answer (score 0):

"И ненависть с далеких этих пор Ведет с любовью **бесконечный спор**".

**Бесконечность** — это общее понятие, применимое ко многим предметам (время, пространство, линия, ряд, а также (в переносном смысле) — вопросы, ожидание и др. **Бескрайним** называют пространство, в этой теме слова могут быть синонимами.

**БЕСКОНЕЧНЫЙ**,  1. Книжн. **Не имеющий начала и конца**, пределов, границ (противоп.: конечный). Время и пространство бесконечны. Б-ая десятичная дробь (матем.; с неограниченным числом десятичных знаков после запятой). // **Безграничный, бескрайний (о пространствах)**. Б-ая степь. Б-ое небо.

**БЕСКРАЙНИЙ**, Не имеющий видимых пределов, края; безграничный, беспредельный. Б-ие степи. Б-ая даль.

Comment: И как вот понимать: общее понятие бесконечности оговаривается его "начальностью"?

Comment: Начало и конец – условные понятия, даже с точки зрения языка, так как речь идет о границах. Исконный – это изначальный,  корень "чать" в кончать и начать

Comment: Всё хорошо, только корень-то не "чать"...